# Background image opacity in angular2

Tags: css, image, angular, opacity

I'm trying to change the opacity of a background image, by setting the RGBA. However the opacity of the background image does not change. Below is the code snippet i'm using with.

Changing the background image opacity this way works in HTML, but not when I try it with angular2.

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles: [`

.background-image {
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
},

`],
    template:
            `
            <h1>Hello Angular</h1>
              <div class="background-image" style="background-image : url('http://v4.pingendo.com/assets/photos/food/cover-1.jpg')">
              </div>
            `,
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Just wanted to say thanks to everyone for jumping in an helping to solve the problem

Comment: Please try `:host .background-image {`

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. I just tried :host .background-image { in place of .background-image { and the result is the same. image is loaded but the opacity has not changed.

Comment: I thought the background image was unaffected by the background color property (since images typically have their own colours).

Answer (score 1):

Try CSS Image Opacity / Transparency like,

```
background-image {
    opacity: 0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40); /* For IE8 and earlier */
}
```

Comment: Thanks @blasteralfred that worked but made the image lighter. The reason   I used rbga was to darken the background image. Opacity appears to make the image lighter.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CSS Pseudo-elements, as in any html. This is not related to Angular2.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/sXeRUYNtOGv974mqrYjj?p=preview)

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    styles: [`
        .background-image{
          position: absolute;
          top: 0px;
          left: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          z-index:-2;
        }
        .background-image:after {
          content: ' ';
          z-index: -1;
          top: 0px;
          left: 0px;
          width: 100%;
          height: 100%;
          position: absolute;
          background-size: cover;
          background-position: center;
          background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        },
    `],
    template:
          `
            <h1>Hello Angular</h1>
            <div class="background-image" style="background-image : url('http://v4.pingendo.com/assets/photos/food/cover-1.jpg')">
            </div>
          `,
})
export class AppComponent { }
```

Comment: Thanks @Abdulrahman, I'm not sure why your solution works and mine doesn't. Here is a link to my plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5HxQjQSAiXl5AUhty13w?p=preview)

Comment: @MJDude When using the Pseudo `:after`, it's like adding another `div` after the current one.  The newly added one is above the original one. `:after` is z-index:-1 while original z-index:-2. So it'll help to think of them as two different divs. The one above has a background-color while the one below has a background-image

Comment: @MJDude in your plunker, the background-color and background-image are on the same div. Which will make the background-image above the background-color.

Comment: Thank you for explaining, that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

Just to close out the thread, I ended up having to manually darken the image in Photoshop :(.

Hopefully this isn't an angular 2 bug.

Comment: Hard to imagine this is Angular related even though you say that it works in HTML. Can you create a Plunker that allows to reproduce?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Thanks for getting back. Here is a link to my plunker [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5HxQjQSAiXl5AUhty13w?p=preview) . It appears Abdulrahman has posted a solution.

Comment: I moved it out of the Angular component but it still doesn't work http://plnkr.co/edit/3t2zWpMOoOjFG9YbQLXQ?p=preview.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer You are right, It looks like when converting the HTML / CSS  to Angular 2. I missed an additional CSS class.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer not to go for opacity/filter.

I think best way to put opacity to the background image which support most of the browser is as follows:

1. Using img tag with 100% height and width with lowest z-index and add opacity or other css whatever you want. Using img tag gives it visibility for search engine as well.
2. If I don't want search engine visibility then I use multiple background.

   background:background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.37),url('img/img.png');